# MySQL División de resultados de dos subquerys

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos subquerys relativamente complejas que dan como resultado algo por el estilo (muy simplificado).

```
SubQuery1 
+----+
| 20 |
| 10 |
| 15 |
| 30 |
+----+
Subquery2
+---+
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 5 |
+---+
```

Y quiero obtener algo como esto, una division fila a fila

```
Result
+----+
| 10 |
|  5 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
+----+
```

He algo básico del estilo SELECT(subquery1)/(subquery2); pero me da error "Subquery returns more than 1 row". Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Si tenes ese resultado, tenes que dividir fila a fila.

Cada subquery devuelve un monton de filas, pero esas columnas tienen nombre. Por lo tanto, si sabes como unir las filas (con un join), lo unico que tenes que hacer en el select es

```
select s1.columna1/s2.columna2 as resultado 
from (subquery1) as s1 inner join (subquery2) as s2 
    on s1.columnajoin = s2.columnajoin
```

Los select se resuelven de a 1 fila por vez, no todos juntos...

Comment: ¿Qué entiendes por columnajoin? entiendo que columna1 y columna2 son las columnas de mis subquerys pero columnajoin me mató

Comment: las columnas por las que tenes que joinear los dos querys.. como sabes que fila va con que fila de la otra tabla?

Comment: Me traigo los datos ordenados, son dos tablas de igual tamaño, asi que 1 a 1 por orden

Comment: entonces tenes q numerar las filas y joinear por eso.. sql no conoce de orden

Comment: Numerar las filas del resultado ambas subquerys y unir por esa col? Ok gracias amigo

Answer (score 1):

El error te sale porque un select así sin más espera pintarte un valor y te va a mostrar una lista.

Digamos que tienes un query1 con

```
select a, b, c
from table1
```

y un query2 con

```
select d, e, f
from table2
```

Lo que buscas sería algo que usara esos resultados para generar la salida

```
select sq1.a/sq2.d as division
from
(select a,b,c from table1) sq1,
(select d,e,f from table2) sq2
where ...
```

Y ojalá en el where haya condiciones para reducir el conjunto (o ya derecho uses un inner join entre las dos subqueries, como para que no tarde toda la vida.

Comment: eso no va a devolver el resultado esperado.. eso hace un producto cartesiano

Comment: @gbianchi Incluso si le pone las condiciones que le digo que ponga y que no sabemos cuáles son porque ni idea qué relación tienen los datos de las subconsultas?

Comment: en ese caso, explicale como poner condiciones de join en el where ;)